# Writing to a TXT file using BufferedWriter - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write the contents of my ArrayList to a text file which is already created in my G drive ( the path has been mentioned below ). I am using BufferedWriter to write the contents of the Arraylist into the text file

It compiles without any errors but somehow the textfile- sampleOutput.txt is empty. Any ideas why this is so ?

```
public void WriteOutput( ArrayList<detailTom> tomData1)
{
      try 
      {
          BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("G:/sampleOutput.txt"));
          for (detailTom detail : tomData1) 
            {

                writer.write(detail.toString());
            }

      } 

      catch (IOException ex) 
      {
          Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } 
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try closing the BufferedWriter object after you finish writing:

> ```
>     public void WriteOutput( ArrayList<detailTom> tomData1){
>       try{
>           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("G:/sampleOutput.txt"));
>           for (detailTom detail : tomData1) {
>   writer.write(detail.toString());
>             }
> ```

```
    writer.close();
```

> ```
>    } 
>
>       catch (IOException ex) 
>       {
>           Logger.getLogger(MyInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
>       } 
> }
> ```